# Derivative of a function which is treated as a variable

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, partial-derivative, differential-operators

I have got a function $f=f(x)$. The derivative is $\partial_xf$. There are applications in which it is reasonable to treat $f$ as another variable in a larger context. In my application I now need an expression for the derivative with respect to $f$ of $\partial_xf$, i.e. $\partial_f(\partial_xf)$. I don't know much about operator calculus. Does
$$\partial_f(\partial_xf)=\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\overset{?}{=}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\partial_x$$
hold? Is $\partial_x$ the correct expession? If yes: How can it be shown? If not: What is the right one?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{ \partial f} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial f}$

Comment: @hickslebummbumm Sorry, but I don't get it. What did you do in the first step?

Comment: In general: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(y(x)) = \frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$. Here $f \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $y \equiv x$ and $x \equiv f$

Comment: @hickslebummbumm Ok, thanks. On the right hand side you then mean $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial f}$, right? But isn't this $=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, because the rest cancels out?

Comment: You cannot simply treat derivatives like divisions. Take for instance $f(x) = \exp(x)$. According to your formula you'd get $\exp(x)$ but $\partial_{\exp(x)} (\partial_x \exp(x)) = \partial_{\exp(x)} \exp(x) = 1$ and $f = \exp(x) \implies x = \ln(f)$ so $\frac{\partial^2 \exp(x)}{\partial_x^2} \frac{\partial \ln(f)}{\partial f} = \exp(x) \frac{1}{f} = \exp(x) \frac{1}{\exp(x)} = 1$.